# HTML link problem

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, sliding-doors

**Hi,**

I have a couple of links(`a`) that uses sliding door, when I have visited one of the links the color of the text will change. With firebug I can see that the link gets the following style:

```
#signInForm a:link, a:visited {
  color: #2277BB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The strange part is that the link do not exists inside the `<div id="SignInForm"></div>`? And this problem shows in FireFox but not IE8.

Pleas take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/ecWzz/

Why do the link get this style?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#signInForm a:link` selects an unvisited link within the `signInForm` `div`, `a:visited` selects *all* `a:visited` links. To restrict the style to just those `a` elements within the `signInForm` `div` use:

```
#signInForm a:link, #signInForm a:visited {
     /* CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need this:

```
#signInForm a:link, #signInForm a:visited {
    ...
```

Your code is asking for *all* `a:visited` to have that style.

Answer (score 2):

```
, a:visited
```

The comma makes it match any link